# Ethereum metamask payment on website not working

Tags: web3js, javascript

im trying to integrate a metamask ethereum payment button on my website but nothing happens when the button is pressed, any help with this? This is the script i got

```
    window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
      if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
        try {
          await ethereum.enable();
          initPayButton()
        } catch (err) {
          $('#status').html('User denied account access', err)
        }
      } else if (window.web3) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)
        initPayButton()
      } else {
        $('#status').html('No Metamask (or other Web3 Provider) installed')
      }
    })

    const initPayButton = () => {
      $('.pay-button').click(() => {
        // paymentAddress is where funds will be send to
        const paymentAddress = '0x192c96bfee59158441f26101b2db1af3b07feb40'
        const amountEth = 1

        web3.eth.sendTransaction({
          to: paymentAddress,
          value: web3.toWei(amountEth, 'ether')
        }, (err, transactionId) => {
          if  (err) {
            console.log('Payment failed', err)
            $('#status').html('Payment failed')
          } else {
            console.log('Payment successful', transactionId)
            $('#status').html('Payment successful')
          }
        })
      })
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: I need help please

Answer (score 0):

I am usually using `ethersjs`. But as far as I remember in the web3js you have to submit your transaction with `.send()` or `.call()` functions. I believe this will work:

```js
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
          to: paymentAddress,
          value: web3.toWei(amountEth, 'ether')
        }, (err, transactionId) => {
          if  (err) {
            console.log('Payment failed', err)
            $('#status').html('Payment failed')
          } else {
            console.log('Payment successful', transactionId)
            $('#status').html('Payment successful')
          }
        }).send()
```